# Multiple parameters sent from a single input field

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a MVC.NET application which has multiple filters. My database has a lot of information about cars.

I want to implement Input field in which the user can type 
"Toyota Yaris 1.6 Petrol" and get results back matching this. The problem is
parsing this on the back end. I have created a way of parsing this but involves the user specifying keys such as "make", "model".

Currently my website can do the following: "make=toyota,model=yaris,engine_size=1.6,fueltype=Petrol". As you can see this is very complicated for the user. But I need those keys to get the values on the back end and match them to the proper queries.

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" name="filterPageSearchModel.GlobalSearchFilter" data-toggle="popover"  data-html="true" id="PartCarSearchField"
                               data-placement="left" title="Example"
                                data-content="<a id='make' onclick='AppendText(this.id)'>make=</a> audi, 
                        <a id='model' onclick='AppendText(this.id)'> model=</a> a4,
                        <a id='enginesize' onclick='AppendText(this.id)'> enginesize=</a> 1.6, 
                        <a id='ribs' onclick='AppendText(this.id)'> ribs=</a> 7,
                        <a id='teeth' onclick='AppendText(this.id)'> teeth=</a> 9, 
                        <a id='voltage' onclick='AppendText(this.id)'> voltage=</a> 12,
                        <a id='amp' onclick='AppendText(this.id)'> amp=</a> 34 a,
                        <a id='power' onclick='AppendText(this.id)'> power=</a>2.0kw,
                        <a id='fueltype' onclick='AppendText(this.id)'> fueltype=</a>petrol"/>

 public IQueryable<PartMMi>GlobalSearchItems(string SearchValues)
    {
        Dictionary<string,string> ConvertedValues = ValuesConverter(SearchValues);
        AutoPartDataClassesDataContext contextAp = new AutoPartDataClassesDataContext();
        InternalDbDataClassesDataContext Context = new InternalDbDataClassesDataContext();
        List<PartMMi> results = new List<PartMMi>();
        var resultMMi = Context.mmis.AsQueryable();

        foreach (var value in ConvertedValues)
        {
            if (LibraryOfParameters.ContainsKey(value.Key)){
                LibraryOfParameters[value.Key] = value.Value;
            }
        }

        if (LibraryOfParameters["make"].Length>0)
            resultMMi = resultMMi.Where(x => x.car.make.Contains(LibraryOfParameters["make"]));
        if (LibraryOfParameters["model"].Length > 0)
            resultMMi = resultMMi.Where(x => x.car.model.Contains(LibraryOfParameters["model"]));
        if (LibraryOfParameters["enginesize"].Length > 0)
            resultMMi = resultMMi.Where(x => x.car.engine_size == Convert.ToDouble(LibraryOfParameters["enginesize"]));


 private Dictionary<string, string> LibraryOfParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "make", ""},
            { "model", ""},
            { "enginesize", ""},
            { "ribs", ""},
            { "teeth", ""},
            { "voltage", ""},
            { "amp", ""},
            { "power", ""},
            {"fueltype","" }
        };

public Dictionary<string,string> ValuesConverter(string OriginalSearchValues)
    {
        List<string> splitSearchString = OriginalSearchValues.Split(',').ToList();

        Dictionary<string, string> SearchParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (string item in splitSearchString)
        {
            string temp1 = item.Split('=').FirstOrDefault();
            string temp2 = item.Split('=').LastOrDefault();
            SearchParameters.Add(temp1.ToLower().Trim(), temp2.Trim());
        }
        return SearchParameters;
    }
```

Comment: You need to create a View Model of your filters and create an input field for each filter criteria. I wouldn't recommend using 1 input field then trying to parse out the criteria, users will never input it correctly and it will be highly error prone. Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: Is there a good reason fro trying to do this in a single field? You'd normally approach it with a selection input when coupling to an existing database that you are matching against. That way it's simple(ish) for the user and gauranteed to match the database. Otherwise, If you're going to get a consitent format of input then you could probably use regex to pull out things like engine size and fuel type as there aren't many options, but trying to auto-decide what is model and what is make is going to require a bit of db searching, or lookup tables of some sort.

Comment: So this is my logic so far Input field=> values are send to Controller => Controller sends them to my Business Class .  From there i have 2 functions which break the input and then check againts the Hardcoded Dictionary which values are present in the input and then perform the query.

Comment: @zgood I already have multiple filters filters with multiple input boxes.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb the reason is my users have requested such a field. It should simplify some searches. The following website http://www.lucasee.com/en/shop/ has the functionality I need. If you type in the field "toyota yaris 1.6" somehow it parses it right and it gives you the correct results.

Comment: The tricky part is recognising that they might have typed it in a different order. eg. yaris 1.6 toyota. Your logic has to recognise that yaris is a model not a make. I suppose multiple lookups with scoring per word might be the way forward? I know I spent ages years ago programming a multiple  keyword search in MySQL only to find there was a built in search functionality in MySQL which was infinitely better! Might be worth checking out what options you have directly in the database for multi-word lookups.